# gcov for freebsd kernel code

Tags: freebsd, gcov

I am looking for steps to perform code coverage using gcov tool for FreeBSD kernel code.

So far I have compiled FreeBSD code and looking at the path: /usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC/
, I found .o and .gcno files. How can I make use of these with gcov?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look at tools like gcovr or lcov to produce a graphical summary